# CSS Media Query that isolates iOS Webview from iOS browser

Tags: css, ios, uiwebview

I'm working on a view that renders both as a webview and a webpage on a browser for iOS. I have a styling change that I need applied to only the webview, and not the browser web page (when the styles are used on the browser, it causes issues).

Is there a CSS `media` query that is available that can isolate the webview from the browser webpage, or vice-versa?